# Change elasticsearch settings from Spring

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible to update elasticsearch settings from Spring? I want to do something like:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/_settings -d '{
"index" : {
    "refresh_interval" : "-1"
} }'
```

but using spring data elasticsearch client.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Could you post your code?

Comment: @aleksander-lidtke: I haven't tried anything, because after looking in `spring-data-elasticsearch` api I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: @TuanPham - do you have to update the refresh interval after it's created? or could it be done at creation time?

Comment: @lechuck - after it's created

Answer (score 0):

Before changing the elasticsearch setting, it is recommended that first close the index, modified the setting and then open the index.

I have added the normalizer like -

```
POST /assets/_close

PUT /assets/_settings
{
  "analysis": {
    "normalizer": {
      "lowercase_normalizer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "char_filter": [],
        "filter": ["lowercase"]
      }
    }
  } 
}

POST /assets/_open
```

After changing the setting, update the existing documents by using the bulk update API.

```
POST /_bulk
{"update":{"_id":"59519","_type":"asset","_index":"assets"}}
{"doc":{"facility_id":491},"detect_noop":false}
```

Note - Use 'detect_noop' for detecting noop updates.